# ifelse inside observe in shiny - not waiting for the trigger

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny

At some part of my code I have the following observe object. It works fine until I add an if statment inside it. The statment executes right away when the script runs and does not wait for the action associated to observe to be triggered. What do I have to do in order to "hold the horses" of this if inside observe?

```
observe({
    print("UPDATING COORDS")
    print(input$map_marker_dragend)
    id <- input$map_marker_dragend$id
    lat_nova <- input$map_marker_dragend$lat
    lon_nova <- input$map_marker_dragend$lng
    print(lat_nova)
    print(lon_nova)
    print(WP$df$latitude)
    df2 <- ifelse(is.null(df2), WP$df, df2) # this is the line causing problem
    df2 <- if (is.null(df2)) return(WP$df) else return(df2) # this is a second try to make it work
    df2$latitude[which(WP$df$id == id)] <- lat_nova
    df2$longitude[which(WP$df$id == id)] <- lon_nova
    print(df2$latitude)
    print(df2, width = Inf)

    # declaring to later use
    WP$df2 = df2
  })
```

Basically what I want is that shiny checks if df2 exists... if not than df2 should be WP$df... if yes than df2 = df2 and proceed with calculations.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about whether [`observeEvent`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html) with some combination of `ignoreNULL` and `ignoreInit` might give you the behaviour you're looking for? Or, conversely, using `suspended=TRUE` in your `observe`?

Comment: I'd think `if (is.null(df2)) df2 <- WP$df` would be sufficient. Are you intentionally bypassing the calculation of `$latitude` (etc)? `return` should not be allowing further execution.

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` is vectorized, and the length of the return value is dependent on the length of the conditional (first argument). I'm inferring that your `df2` and `WP$df2` are `data.frame`s, which means that while the length if `is.null(df2)` is length 1, the "length" of `WP$df` is not, it is actually the same as `ncol(WP$df)`. This can be seen here:

```r
length(mtcars)
# [1] 11
ncol(mtcars)
# [1] 11
nrow(mtcars)
# [1] 32

ifelse(TRUE, mtcars, iris)
# [[1]]
#  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4
# [19] 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
```

That is the first column (as a `list`) of `mtcars`. (It might be helpful to know that a `data.frame` is really just a `list` where each element is the same length. In traditional ways, each element is a `vector`, but more complicated objects ("list-columns") can be had as well.)

It is often assumed that the lengths of the `test=`, `yes=`, and `no=` arguments to `ifelse` are either all of the same length or of length 1 (which allows recycling). But this is neither tested nor enforced:

```r
ifelse(TRUE, 1:2, 11:13)
# [1] 1
ifelse(c(FALSE, TRUE), 1, 11:13)
# [1] 11  1ifelse(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), 1, 11:12)
# [1] 11  1 11
```

From this, it can be inferred that the objects are recycled as much as required to fill out to the length of `test=`.

So in your case, your `ifelse(is.null(df), WP$df, df2)` is returning just the first column of one of the two.

Something else about your code: don't use `return`.

I suggest your code should be

```r
observe({
    print("UPDATING COORDS")
    print(input$map_marker_dragend)
    id <- input$map_marker_dragend$id
    lat_nova <- input$map_marker_dragend$lat
    lon_nova <- input$map_marker_dragend$lng
    print(lat_nova)
    print(lon_nova)
    print(WP$df$latitude)
    if (is.null(df2)) df2 <- WP$df
    df2$latitude[which(WP$df$id == id)] <- lat_nova
    df2$longitude[which(WP$df$id == id)] <- lon_nova
    print(df2$latitude)
    print(df2, width = Inf)

    # declaring to later use
    WP$df2 = df2
  })
```

(I'm assuming `WP` is from `reactiveValues`, otherwise the assignment on the last line will not be saved.)

Comment: Hi r2evans, tks for your complete answer. Really appreciated! But unfortunatelly your suggestion didnt work... the app crash right at the start with the following message: "Warning: Error in <observer>: object 'df2' not found". I understand that the object doesnt exist when the app start... what I dont get it is why the if doesnt work properly in this case and why it runs right from the start... my undestand is that it should wait for the observe trigger event to run... I am probably lacking some basic concept. Do you want a full reproducible code to help further? If you have time of course.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea! That's completely in your app, not shared here. That problem suggests your app needs to be restructured.